# what options for quartz PDFDocument.dataRepresentationWithOptions()

Tags: swift, swift2

Does anyone know what options are available to you in the following method?

```
// pdf:PDFDocument
pdf.dataRepresentationWithOptions(options: [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

I'm trying to take a PDF, open it up, search for a specific tag per PDF specs and insert additional tags immediately after that tag.

After editing with PDFDocument methods, I was hoping to convert it a string to search the whole file, so I thought to convert it to a data representation first, and then from there to string. But I suppose I could save it to file, and re-open it from there too so I don't have to convert from the PDFDocument object directly.